# should i push development.rb and production.rb to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am able to get apps working on heroku in general - but I recently started using Amazon S3 for images.  I can make the process work if I hard code my access keys. But if I set the variables on heroku and then use

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['rails-apps-production'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

in my production.rb file it doesnt work.  However, it does work if I use the development.rb code to reference a .yml file with the keys - but I dont want to make that .yml file public and compromise my keys.  I know I am doing something wrong.  - Should I only be deploying the production.rb file and not the development.rb file? Are they causing conflict?  Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: have you actually set those environment values? try typing `heroku config --app YOURAPPNAME` to set one use eg: `heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY=12345 --app YOURAPPNAME`

Comment: oh, and otherwise yes you're doing the right thing.

Comment: I was just running the config access keys using the heroku toolbelt while in the local directory where the app is.  I will try this now.  Thanks!

Comment: yeah that probably sets it up, but maybe gets overwritten every time you deploy a new version. ??? using `heroku config:set` is the "proper" way to do it so it's there for every deploy

Comment: i think the error is in my model

Comment: 'code' class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
 acts_as_votable
 belongs_to :user

 has_attached_file :image, storage: :s3, s3_credentials: 'config/s3.yml', styles: { medium: "300x300"}
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end

Comment: the model is referencing my .yml file that i have in my gitignore file becuase i dont want to push that to github...

Comment: That sounds like a very different error to the one you're talking about here. Note: heroku will not have any access to a file that you haven't actually pushed to git - so you'll have to do something different than a local yml file for your prod system.

Comment: @shutdown23 - rather than posting code in comments, edit your question. The lack of formatting in comments makes them very hard to read